# When does Time Dependent workflow rule executes?

Tags: salesforce

I have set a time dependent workflow rule on certain condition which is below...
after  6 days of particular(1st follow-up date ->in my case) date the workflow  rule should update the picklist field(current status -> in my case)....

My question is at what time on 6th day it will execute ?
Do we have control on this time ?

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 2):

We only control the day of execution because :
1.  Salesforce evaluates time-based workflow on the organization's time zone, not the users'. Users in different time zones may see differences in          behavior.
2.  Time-dependent actions aren't executed independently. They're grouped into a single batch that starts executing within one hour after the first action enters the batch.
3.  Time triggers don't support minutes or seconds.
4.  Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its Edition,
     Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time triggers to the next hour.

Comment: Hi Ajay, does that mean like the particular field update action will happen at any random time on that day which we have set?